# Keeping a consistent parentId/id relationship with a flatten function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Suppose I have a nested object list like this:

```
[{
    "id": "a",
    "name": "Object a",
    "parentId": "root",
    "children": [{
        "id": "c",
        "name": "Object c"
    },{
        "id": "d",
        "name": "Object D",
        "parentId": "a"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "b",
    "name": "Object b",
    "parentId": "root"
}]
```

The object anatomy is simple: `id`, `name`, `children` (if any) and `parentId`. I'm using this flatten function that turns the nested object
into a flat array:

```js
 function flatten(array) {
  var result = [];
  array.forEach(function (a) {
      result.push(a);
      if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
          result = result.concat(flatten(a.children));
      }
  });
  return result;
}
```

The thing is that the `parentId` value is not always persistent for every object, and therefore when the object gets flattened into an array, it's possible to lose a parent & child object relationship.

I need the `flatten` method to rebuild the parentId value according to the object structure. And there's only one catch, if the object is not a child, then it should have a parentId of `root`.

Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow correctly, you just want to flatten your structure into an array that maintains the `parentId` relationship inherent in the original tree.  If so, then I believe this will do:

```js
const flatten = (xs, parentId = 'root') =>
  xs .flatMap (({children = [], id, ...rest}) => [
    {id, ...rest, parentId}, 
    ... flatten (children, id)
  ])

const input = [{id: "a", name: "Object a", parentId: "root", children: [{id: "c", name: "Object c"},{id: "d", name: "Object D", parentId: "a"}]}, {id: "b", name: "Object b", parentId: "root"}]

console .log (flatten (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

It's a fairly simple recursion, using `flatMap` to combine the records and parameter destructuring (with default a parameter for `children`) to simplify our object handling.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to add the `parentId` to the objects that don't have them. Change

```
result = result.concat(flatten(a.children));
```

to

```
result = result.concat(flatten(a.children.map(addParent(a.parentId)));
```

```
const addParent = parentId => item => ({ ...item, parentId });
```

where the root is called with a `parentId` of `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parentId in as the second argument to your flatten function like so, with the default parent just being "root".

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "a",
    "name": "Object a",
    "parentId": "root",
    "children": [{
        "id": "c",
        "name": "Object c"
    },{
        "id": "d",
        "name": "Object D",
        "parentId": "a"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "b",
    "name": "Object b",
    "parentId": "root"
}]

function flatten(array, parentId = "root") {
  let result = [];
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    a.parentId = parentId;
    result.push(a);
    if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
      result = result.concat(flatten(a.children, a.id));
    }
    delete a.children; // optional
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```